# Celery briefly replaces %n in filenames with the queue names instead of the respective worker names on restart

Tags: celery, django-celery

I have noticed that whenever celery is restarted via `celery multi restart 1 --pidfile=/var/run/celery/%n.pid` (I have it daemonized in a service file under `ExecReload`), the filenames for files such as PID file, LOG file where %n is there, is replaced with the list of queue names briefly instead of the actual worker name(s). This leads to a LockFailed error while reading the PID file in `celery/platforms.py > write_pid`, due to file name being too long. But it gets fine once the worker names are there.

I tried to look it up but couldn't find anything relevant. Why is this happening? I am currently using version 4.2.2 and I didn't see this behaviour mentioned anywhere in the docs although ChatGPT did mention this behaviour but without any source.